# Terraform Plan and Apply hung in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I want to run some terraform scripts in EC2 instance to create an EC2 instance. I have deployed Ubuntu 22 in AWS and installed terraform on the Ubuntu EC2 machine.

I have put all the tf files in the Ubuntu machine and the terraform init downloaded all the provider plugins. Also installed aws cli and created a test user with Administrator policy. With aws configure, entered the creds in the ubuntu machine. However the terraform plan is getting hung for a long time and when I cancel it (crtl + c), I get the below error,

```
Error: configuring Terraform AWS Provider: validating provider credentials: retrieving caller identity from STS: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, request canceled, context canceled
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on provider.tf line 13, in provider "aws":
│   13: provider "aws" {
```

I tried to recreate a new EC2 machine with Amazn linux and still it did not work. The security group has 0.0.0.0/0 inbound access and also the Subnet routetable has a Internet gateway. The EC2 has public IP accessible.

Comment: please provide us with your provider code

Comment: hi @Darren, code below,


`
# Terraform Block
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.0" # which means any version equal & above 0.14 like 0.15, 0.16 etc and < 1.xx
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

# Provider Block
provider "aws" {
  region  = 'ap-south-1'
}
`

Comment: perhaps , create an instance profile and a role with the necessary permissions for your tf deployments . And then run `aws sts get-caller-identity` you should expect a response . Its recommended to rather use a role than hardcode credentials onto the ec2 ... It just appears that terraform is struggling to get the neccessary credentials to perform api requests . Alternatively, You could possibly just add the secret key and access key in the provider block (for testing purposes)

provider "aws" {
  region     = "ap-south-1"
  access_key = "my-access-key"
  secret_key = "my-secret-key"
}